# Why does the bitwise ~ operator change the size of the unsigned char?

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I have a function which accepts a `uint8_t` variable. When I use the **bitwise complement** i.e. `~` operator on the parameter value, I get the following warning:

```
warning: conversion to 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' from 'int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
   func(~ui);
```

Here is a working [example](https://godbolt.org/z/r53dr3zj3):

```cpp
void func(uint8_t ui) {}

int main() {  

  uint8_t ui{0xF0};

  // Without compl operator it works
  func(ui);

  // Getting warning: conversion to 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' 
  // from 'int' may alter its value
  func(~ui); 

  // Here the ~ operator changes the 8-bit ui to 32-bit
  std::cout << "ui: " << std::bitset<sizeof(ui)*8>(ui) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "~ui: " << std::bitset<sizeof(~ui)*8>(~ui) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

which generates the following output:

```cpp
ui: 11110000
~ui: 11111111111111111111111100001111
```

I've read and tested the example at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/compl). They use a `bitset` which uses a byte storage per bit and does not elaborate on the case when using the operator only on a **single byte**. I also checked [cplusplus](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/#bitwise) which does not explain why either.

Thus, why can't you use the `~` operator (and I've checked the other bitwise operators as well) on a `uint8_t` without it changing the `uint8_t` to an `int`?

Comment: You are looking for "integer promotion".

Comment: Does this mean all bitwise operators promote to integer?

Comment: Operands that are smaller than `int` are promoted to `int` first, so `ui` is `uint8_t`, but `~ui` is `int`.

Comment: I would recommend checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46073296/1143634) answer